# div center does not work for IE

Tags: css

I have this css

```
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto;
top:50%;
width:15px;
height:15px;
background-color:#fff;
-moz-border-radius: 15px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
cursor:pointer;
```

Its centering fine on chrome and stays on top for IE and ff.

removed and changed position:

whats wrong here?

Thanks
Jean

Comment: How does the html look like? Did you add text-align: center to the parent element?

Answer (score 0):

```
#div {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:-7.5px; // Half your width in negative
    margin-top:-7.5px; // Half your height in negative
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background-color:#fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

This will work in all browsers. IE renderings can be awful with valid code, but this a tried and tested method for me for universal workings.

To edit this, simply change the negative margins values to match half the height, or width of your div element.

Comment: The div has to be at the center of the page

Comment: This code renders centered the dimensions provided for me in IE6 - 8 and other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 0 auto;` for horizontal centering should work fine for IE6+, but only as long as you are in Standards Mode. Make sure you [include a Standards Mode doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_Mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes) in your HTML, or you'll fall into Quirks Mode, where nothing works properly.

To find out whether a particular page is in Standards Mode, enter `javascript:alert(document.compatMode)` into the address bar. `CSS1Compat` is good; `BackCompat` is Quirks.

For vertical centering without absolute-positioning, that `top: 50%` only makes sense if the parent element has an explicit height. So if you are intending to push the top down to half of the browser height, then you'll need to specify `100%` height on each ancestor of the element, eg. at least:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `margin-top: 30%;` instead of `top:50%;`
No `position:relative;` require.

**EDIT**
For align center in IE, I use div-wrapper for help.
This is all my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            #myDivWrapper {
                text-align: center; /* x axis for ie*/
            }
            #myDiv {
                /* set position */
                margin: 0 auto; /* x axis */
                margin-top: 30%; /* y axis */

                /* draw div */
                background-color: red;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='myDivWrapper'>
            <div id='myDiv'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```